# iframe parent getElementById , if found refresh parent page only once

Tags: iframe

I have an iframe within a parent page (on the same domain). I need parent page to refresh only once when iframe contain div id 'recentlyViewedJobs'.

this didn't work

```
document.frames('myiframe').document.getElementById('recentlyViewedJobs').innerHTML = "http://www.mysite.com";
```

Comment: if(document.getElementById("myid") !== null)
{ window.location.href = "http://www.google.com"
}     this didn't work either.

Comment: <script> if ( $('my id')[0] ) { window.top.location = "http://www.site.com" } didnt work. Anyone can help here ?